# oracle (12c) regexp_substr to split filename and directoryname

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c, I'd like to split string containing full filename (including directory) to 2 strings : first one with the directory, second with the filename.

I already got filename but can't extract directory correctly :

```
select
   val,
   regexp_substr(val, '[^/]+/[^/]+', 1, 1) as dirname,
   regexp_substr(val, '[^/]+$', 1, 1) as filename
from (select '/a/b/c/d/e/f/file.ext' as val from dual) t
```

This gives:

```
dirname = a/b -- This is my purpose...
filename = file.ext -- This is correct !
```

I'd like to get dirname as

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

including the 1st "/"

NB : I don't want to split into several lines (using connect by sentence). 
I need to get one row with 2 seperate strings...

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need (slow) regular expressions and can just use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( val ) AS
  SELECT '/a/b/c/d/e/f/file.ext' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( val, 1, INSTR( val, '/', -1 ) ) AS dir,
       SUBSTR( val, INSTR( val, '/', -1 ) + 1 ) AS filename
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DIR           | FILENAME
> :------------ | :-------
> /a/b/c/d/e/f/ | file.ext
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=902313b1c4138556730335fdcb0d07d5)*

Comment: Note that the OP does not appear to want the final `/` in the directory name.  Also, the performance of a particular regex depends on the pattern being used.

Comment: `SUBSTR( val, 1, INSTR( val, '/', -1 ) - 1 )` if you don't want the final slash.

Comment: Very much agree with this.  REGEXP functions are slow and should not be used where non-REGEXP equivalents work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

We can try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '/[^/]*$', '') AS path,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '[^/]+$') AS filename
FROM yourTable;
```

The basic strategy here is to remove the final slash and all proceeding it to obtain the directory path, and do the opposite to obtain the filename.

Comment: Thanks... I completely forgot regexp_replace !